# woocommerce product add on products category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I got the woocommerce product add on plugin.
I am trying to have a custom text under each product in the category product list. Right now I am able to have that only in the product page.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

I was able to add variable by adding this to functions

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ) ) {

function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ($product->product_type == "variable" && (is_product() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
        woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
    }
    else {
        woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' );
    }
}
```